# Does replacing 'local' with 'global' in the definition of viscosity sub(super)solution change the definition?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $F(x,u,Du,D^2u)=0$ for $x\in\Omega$ be our equation of interest. One way of defining a viscosity subsolution is this:

We say $u$ is a viscosity subsolution iff for any test function $\phi\in C^2(\Omega)$ such that $u-\phi$ has a LOCAL maximum at $x_0$ then $F(x_0,D\phi(x_0),D^2\phi(x_0))\leq 0$.

However in  this paper, definition 2.1 on page 6

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.52.8750&rep=rep1&type=pdf

the author replace the word local with GLOBAL. I believe this is fairly common in optimal control/stopping literature.

I think the answer is no, as long as we can solve this seemingy simple analysis question

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638457/finding-a-smooth-function-which-dominates-a-continuous-one

but I have struggled to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, and how to solve the analysis question is explained in exercise 3.5 in [Albert Fathi's lecture notes](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEcQFjAC&url=http://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~pbernard/enseignement/m2/fathi.pdf&ei=_HzWUuzuG86r0gWLl4GADQ&usg=AFQjCNF6bx0iQFYFSBuEa6n_KA8RemSELw&sig2=VL9hcdctrCfU7_wuBEpABA&bvm=bv.59378465,d.d2k) for example -there are other sources of course, but not freely available.

Comment: That would do. If i write something on this, what should i reference? In the paper i referred to, i think this was just assumed.

Comment: @lost1 you can quote Barles' book, for example, Guy Barles. Solutions de viscosit\´e des \´equations de Hamilton-Jacobi. Springer-
Verlag, Paris, 1994.

Comment: I flipped through the content page and this book seems to be interested in first order only, am I mistaken?

Comment: @lost1 Viscosity solutions  are introduced first for second order problem, as it is more 'natural' in this case, and then for first order. The general theory is done for both.