# Equivalence of alternative definitions of 'viscosity solution'

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Consider the first-order Hamilton-Jacobi equation (HJ):

$$H(x,u,\nabla u) = 0 \quad \text{ on } \ \Omega,$$ where  $\Omega$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $u:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, and $H:\Omega \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ (*Hamiltonian*) is continuous.

**Definition 1 (Crandall-Lions-Evans):** We say that $u \in C(\Omega)$ is a viscosity solution of (HJ) iff, $\forall \phi \in C^1(\Omega)$,

$\forall x_0$ point of local maximum of $u-\phi$, $\ H(x_0, u(x_0), \nabla\phi(x_0)) \le 0$;

$\forall x_0$ point of local minimum of $u-\phi$, $\ H(x_0, u(x_0), \nabla\phi(x_0)) \ge 0$.

---

**Q1:** Where can I find a detailed proof that we can replace

- "local maximum" by "strict local maximum" or "global maximum" or "strict global maximum";
- "local minimum" by "strict local minimum" or "global minimum" or "strict global minimum"

and obtain an equivalent definition? (Or anyway how would that proof go?)

**Q2:** Is it true that we can replace  $C^1$ by $C^k$ or $C^k_{\text{comp}}$, with $1 < k \le \infty$, and obtain an equivalent definition?

Comment: Just get the ball rolling, surely we can replace the test function $\phi$ by compactly supported ones because all conditions here are local.

Comment: @FanZheng: That's right. Thanks for your remark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the subsolution case is proven, as the supersolution case is identical.

**Q1**

Suppose $u$ is a subsolution under the definition with strict extremum. Let $\phi$ be a test function such that $u-\phi$ has a **possibly nonstrict** maximum at $x_0$. Let
$$\psi(x)=\phi(x)+|x-x_0|^2$$
so that $x_0$ is a strict maximum of $u-\psi$. Moreover,
$$H(x_0,u,\nabla \phi(x_0)) = H(x_0,u,\nabla \psi(x_0)) \leq 0.$$

**Q2**

Suppose $u$ is a subsolution under the definition with compact test functions and $1 < k < \infty$. Let $\phi$ be a **noncompact** test function such that $u-\phi$ has a local maximum at $x_0$. Let $B_r$ denote the Euclidean ball of radius $r$ around $x_0$. Without loss of generality, we assume that $B_3 \subset \Omega$ (otherwise, perform some scaling to fix things). Now, let
\begin{align*}
\psi(x)&=\phi(x) 1_{B_1}(x) + \zeta(x) \phi(\hat{x}) 1_{B_2 \setminus B_1}(x),\\
\zeta(x)&=\exp(1-1/(1-|x-\hat{x}|^{2k})),
\end{align*}
and $\hat{x}$ is the unique closest point to $x$ in $\operatorname{cl}B_1$.  $\psi$ inherits all the local properties of $\phi$ at $x_0$ and hence
$$H(x_0,u,\nabla \phi(x_0)) = H(x_0,u,\nabla \psi(x_0)) \leq 0.$$
The supersolution case is identical.

Comment: Thank you. So this answer leaves open only the cases "global maximum" (or "minimum") and replacing $C^1$ with $C^k$, $1 < k \le \infty$.

Comment: Also, what is the motivation behind defining $\zeta$ that way?

Comment: @Kei: The global case is already handled by my answer in Q1. To answer your second question, intuitively, $\zeta$ is used to mollify the value of $\psi$ on $\partial B_{1}$ (where it is equal to $\varphi$) with its value on $\partial B_{2}$ (where it is equal to zero). The $C^k$ replacement can be obtained by a density argument.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 1. Why is the global case already handled? 2. What kind of density argument are you thinking of?

Comment: Oh sorry. I misread your question. The answer handles "global max" $\iff$ "strict global max". I believe the idea is similar for "local max" $\iff$ "global max". Start with a test function in which a local max is admitted and try to turn that local max into a global max while maintaining all of the local properties. As for the density argument, start with a test function in $C^1$ and approximate it by $C^k$ functions via mollification.

Comment: Here's a reference for the local iff global argument: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/154542/does-replacing-local-with-global-in-the-definition-of-viscosity-subsuperso